# Font not being recognized in web app

Tags: css, fonts

I have created a website based on Grails web framework that uses Groovy.
For some reason I'm not able to get the fonts to load properly.

I'm using: `font-family: "Avenir Next Ultra Light","Avenir Next";`

On my Mac, the font loads perfectly using Safari and Chrome but not on Firefox. On other systems I've noticed that the font doesn't load at all.

I understand that it's a paid font but just not sure what to do to get the font incorporated into the site properly.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: post more CSS?  are you using @font-face ?

Comment: Check this out - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/ and http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: If you haven't used the `@font-face` and it is a non standard font, it will only show on machines that have that font installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the font file somewhere on the server.

```
@font-face {
 font-family: NAME;
 src: url('/FILEPATH/FILENAME.ttf');
}

p {
 font-family: NAME;
}
```

Browser Support: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

EDIT: And, as Alex K. said, make sure you have a license if it's a commercial font.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand we need to store it on the server. Do I need to call @font-face every time I want to use the font?

Also, since it is a Commercial font we need to get the license - I'm at myfonts.com and trying to figure which one to get. Do we need only the Webfonts version (WOFF,EOT,TTF,SVG)?

Comment: Just call @font-face once at the top of the stylesheet. From there you can assign the font to elements as normal. TTF/OTF will work for everything but IE might act funny so use EOT or WOFF as well. the license you mentioned has all those so you should be good.

Comment: Really appreciate all the help. How would I load the 2 files? Just add a second src: url('/FILEPATH/FILENAME.eot'); so that it can support IE?

Comment: @font-face { font-family: NAME; src: url('/FILEPATH/FILENAME.ttf'), url('/FILEPATH/FILENAME.eot'); } You might as well just list off all the formats you have. The browser should just use whichever it likes best.

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak for FireFox but a more important fact is that the font must exist in an appropriate format on all machines viewing the page. If the font does not exist as an installed font it must be embedded in the page, something you need a license for if its a commercial font.

I would suggest browsing for something similar and using the boilerplate from https://www.google.com/fonts.